# Could not find JAVA home Elastcisearch

Tags: elasticsearch, java-home

I installed `Elasticsearch 6.2`,`Kibana`and`logstash`.
I created a file in bin\elasticsearch\launchELK.cmd, that contain just 2 lines:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161"  

elasticsearch.bat
```

I added on a system variable a JAVA_HOME.

When I write `java -version:`

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

When I write `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161
```

And finally when I run elasticsearch by the file `launchELK.cmd`, this is the rsult:

```
bin>  lancerELK.cmd

bin> set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161"

bin> elasticsearch.bat

Le chemin d'accès spécifié est introuvable
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH
```

Someone can help me please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `elasticsearch.bat` file then try to start elasticsearch.

Comment: This worked for me (in the bat): set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171. No idea why it doesn't work if you do this prior to running the batch.

Comment: In the bat file, don't surround the path with quotes. Instead `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12`